# Open remote file via http

Tags: perl, http, module, screen-scraping

Is there any perl module like File::Remote, that works over http (read only)? Something like

```
$magic_module->open( SCRAPE, "http://somesite.com/");
while(<SCRAPE>)
{
  #do something     
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, of course. You can use `LWP::Simple`:

```
use LWP::Simple;
my $content = get $url;
```

Don't forget to check if the content is not empty:

```
die "Can't download $url" unless defined $content;
```

`$content` will be `undef` it some error occurred during downloading.

Comment: how to convert OI:File object ?

Answer (score 3):

Also you can use [`File::Fetch`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aFetch) module:

```
File::Fetch
    ->new(uri => 'http://google.com/robots.txt')
    ->fetch(to => \(my $file));
say($file);
```

Answer (score 3):

With [HTTP::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/HTTP%3a%3aTiny):

```
use HTTP::Tiny qw();
my $response = HTTP::Tiny->new->get('http://example.com/');
if ($response->{success}) {
    print $response->{content};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want unified interface to handle both local, remote (HTTP/FTP) and whatever else files, use [`IO::All`](http://p3rl.org/IO%3a%3aAll) module.

```
use IO::All;

# reading local
my $handle = io("file.txt");
while(defined(my $line = $handle->getline)){
    print $line
}

# reading remote
$handle = io("http://google.com");
while(defined(my $line = $handle->getline)){
    print $line
}
```

Comment: IO::All is good for small command-line hacks, but I can't recommend it in production for precisely the reason shown in the answer: it makes no distinction between files and URIs, opening the door for all sort of injection attacks. That was a stupid idea/security failure for [PHP fopen](http://php.net/fopen), we shouldn't repeat that mistake.

Comment: Of course sanitizing untrusted input issue is relevant to pretty much anything. Still it is good for things far larger than "command-line hacks", as long as you have trusted input. Backend code for example. Additionally, it is easy to write a simple wrapper around `io` for validation.

Comment: Lots of caveats for such a simple task, and better modules exist where a programmer does not need to expend so much thought in order to use it safely and correctly. IO::All is at a disadvantage here.

Comment: I completely disagree. Having one interface instead of what, 10? - it is a huge advantage you'll feel the moment you will want to change source of your **file** (note, even request says "file", not "content of URL") from HTTP to something else with different interface.